# Visual Studio: Is there an incremental search for the entire solution?

Tags: visual-studio, search

I am very fond of the keyboard shortcuts built into Visual Studio. One of my favorites is **Ctrl+i**, which triggers the **incremental search**. It jumps over the text in the current document as I fill in the searchword. After the desired searchword is typed, I use **F3** to jump through the matches.

It works fine, except that is is limited to searching in the **current document**. Also, triggering incremental search, automatically changes the `Look In` option in the `Find And Replace` dialog to **Current Document**.

Is there an incremental search for the entire solution? Is there a keyboard shortcut for it? Or at the very least is there a way to prevent an usage of incremental search from changing the Look In option?

Answer (score 10):

I use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>F</kbd> which is Find in Files. Once I get a list of results, you can hit <kbd>F8</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>F8</kbd> to cycle through them. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>I</kbd> does not affect the scope of this search.

Also, after you've found your first match with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>I</kbd>, you don't have to hit <kbd>F3</kbd>, you can just hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>I</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>I</kbd> to cycle through the matches.

In addition, a quick way to jump to a specific file or class is to use something like [SonicFileFinder](http://www.jens-schaller.de/sonic-tools/sonicfilefinder/overview/overview.htm)

Comment: Thanks John! I wasn't aware of Ctrl+Shift+F since Ctrl+F is the pervasive way to find in any Windows application. This solves half my problem. Now if there was a way to do incremental search over the solution ... :-)

Comment: The short answer to solution-wide incremental search is that it doesn't exist in VS proper. It may be supported in one of the popular add ons like Resharper. I like SonicFileFinder as well for jumping to classes quickly.

Comment: John: SonicFileFinder looks interesting. Go ahead and add it into your answer, so others can discover it too.

Answer (score 1):

ReSharper has some really nice [navigation and search](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/navigation_search.html) features, including an incremental [Go To Type](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/navigation_search.html#Go_to_Type) search which works across the whole solution.

Answer (score 1):

[Visual Sidekick](http://www.visualsidekick.com/Syntaxia/HomePage.php) performs incremental search over the whole solution. You can search for file names and for symbols names as well. This tool has been a huge time saver for the C++ development we do. It is ridiculous that Visual Sidekick works better than Visual Studio's own IntelliSense. It hasn't been updated in a while though and doesn't support Visual Studio 2010 yet. ReSharper doesn't seem to support C++ though.

[Visual Assist X](http://www.wholetomato.com/) supports many languages (C++, C#, VB, ASP/ASP.NET, HTML, XML, JavaScript, VBScript, XAML) but it offers a lot of refactoring tools that usually don't work with C++ (e.g. Find References) because C++ is so difficult to parse (macros, templates, etc).