# find aspx page in object browser or in "find symbols"

Tags: visual-studio, search, ide

Is there a way to find the classes and members of the aspx webpages with the object browser? Or using "Find  Symbol"? Im guessing that I cant

The "Go to Type" of ReSharper solves this?

Questions related:

[Get a list of search results in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343956/get-a-list-of-search-results-in-visual-studio)

[Visual Studio: Is there an incremental search for the entire solution?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/625244/visual-studio-is-there-an-incremental-search-for-the-entire-solution)